Defining rank of an abelian subgroup using second centralizer
I recently came across this article which explored the maximal abelian subgroups of the symmetric group $S_n$. The author defines an "abelian rank" of a maximal abelian subgroup of $S_n$ thusly:

Let $M$ be a maximal abelian subgroup of a non-abelian group $G$. We define the "abelian rank of $M$ as the minimal cardinality of a set $A \subseteq M$ such that $\cup_{a \in A} C^2(a) = M$. The "second centralizer" of $a$, $C^2(a)$ is defined $C^2(a) = \{x \in G : xb = bx \text{ for every } b \in C(a)\}$.

It seems like the abelian rank, as the author defines it, is related to the definition of rank for a non-abelian group (size of the smallest generating set), but it's distinct from that notion. As a matter of fact, the author gives an example of a group of an abelian subgroup of $S_6$ which has abelian rank 2, but is generated by three elements.
$$C^2((12)(34))C^2((12)(56)) \simeq \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$$
As far as I can tell, the use of the second centralizers to define algebraic structures comes from their utilization in finding abelian sub-semigroups. Is this notion of using the second centralizer to define a 'rank' a novel notion for group theory, or has it been studied previously?

This may be difficult,  as it may have been studied during times (as during antiquity before Socrates), when there wasn't any paper yet.   Then again,  group theory is not supposed to be that old.
